# Enable Vault TLS using ACM

Tags: hashicorp-vault, aws-acm

I have a vault behind an ALB and want to enable TLS using ACM in a vault. Can anyone guide me on how I can import ACM in a vault to enable TLS?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the AWS ACM (by requesting a new TLS certificate or by importing your own) and use that created TLS certificate into your ALB and your vault will start working with TLS enabled.

It's simple and no server-level configurations are required. The following video will help you achieve this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GW7RkWUZL4E